# Restoring PostgreSQL Database takes long time

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, database-restore, devart

Using [`Dotconnect For PostgreSQL Connectivity`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/) in my `VB.NET` Program

this is my method to take backup of db

```
  Private Sub pgsqlBackup()
   Dim pgback As New PgSqlDump
   pgback.Connection = Myconnstr
   Myconnstr.Open()
   pgback.ObjectTypes = PgSqlDumpObjects.All
   pgback.Backup("D:\pgBAckup\backupst.dump")
End Sub
```

- size of the `Databse` on the disk is `15MB`
- size of the `Backup`  is `1.99MB`

i have tested the `restore(pgScript)` using `pgAdmin` with the `backup file` mentioned above, it takes long time to restore `5.36 MIN`

why am confused is the above mentioned `databse`is just a test `database` the actual database size at preset is `889 MB`, So is there  any ways to speed up the `restore` process or any other methods for `restore` ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you use `pg_restore` or `psql` directly from the command line does it perform at the expected speed?

Comment: @CraigRinger i didn't try `pg_restore or psql`, which is the best `backup/restore` for `PostgreSQL Database` am just migrated from `MSSQL` to `PostgreSQL `

Comment: `pg_dump -Fc` and `pg_restore`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

A file, named backupst.dump, was created using the PgSqlDump.Backup method. It contains a set of SQL queries for creating the database.

> ...i have tested the restore(pgScript) using pgAdmin with the backup file mentioned above, it takes long time to restore 5.36 MIN...

Devart cannot comment on pgAdmin performance. You can try restoring the database from the backupst.dump file with dotConnect for PostgreSQL, and performance may be better in this case:

1. Try using PgSqlDump.Restore method. For more information, please refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data~Devart.Common.DbDump~Restore.html
2. Try using a PgSqlScript object which allows you to execute multiple queries.  For more information, please refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlScript.html
3. Try using PgSqlCommand with value of UnpreparedExecute property set to true. This also allows you to execute multiple queries. For more information, please refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand~UnpreparedExecute.html